how to forbid optional properties in typescript interface to be undefined
I want to define a typescript interface with optional properties like:
interface SquareConfig {
  color?: string;
  width?: number;
  comments?: string[];
}

the following constants are valid instances:
const a: SquareConfig = {};

const b: SquareConfig = {color: 'red'};

const c: SquareConfig = {
  width: 99,
  comments: ['bla']
};

As well as "d":
const d: SquareConfig = {
  color: undefined,
  comments: undefined
};

How do I define type SquareConfig to not allow undefined properties? "d" should be forbidden, but "e" should be possible:
const e: SquareConfig = {
};

Because there is a difference between these two objects.

Hi, you could set in your TS configuration as described here exactOptionalPropertyTypes: true in this way during your compilation you will receive an error

You can assert your type with a factory function:
interface SquareConfig {
  color?: string;
  width?: number;
  comments?: string[];
}

type CheckConfig<T extends SquareConfig, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = undefined extends T[K] ? never : T;
function makeSquareConfig<T extends SquareConfig>(config: CheckConfig<T>): T{
  return config;
}

const config = makeSquareConfig({
  color: undefined // error
});

const config2 = makeSquareConfig({
  // ok
});

const config3 = makeSquareConfig({
  color: 'red' // ok
});


You can use exactOptionalPropertyTypes.

With exactOptionalPropertyTypes enabled, TypeScript applies stricter rules around how it handles properties on type or interfaces which have a ? prefix.

You even have an example in the official page:
interface UserDefaults {
  // The absence of a value represents 'system'
  colorThemeOverride?: "dark" | "light";
}

const settings = getUserSettings();
settings.colorThemeOverride = "dark";
settings.colorThemeOverride = "light";

// But not:
settings.colorThemeOverride = undefined;
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '"dark" | "light"' with 
'exactOptionalPropertyTypes: true'. Consider adding 'undefined' to the type of 
the target.

